# Ran comments on Gemara Masechet Shabbath

Tags: talmud-gemara, rishonim, maseches-shabbos, authorship, ritva

I did learn several comments of Rishonim on a Suggia in Masechet Shabbath and read a footnote (from Harav Moshe Hershler) on the Ramban (Edition Hamachon Hatalmud Haisraeli).

He refers to a comment by Ran, Shita Leharan and Ritba. I understand that there is a discussion about the identity of the authors of the old edition of Chidushe Haritba, the new edition of Chiddushe Haritba (edition Mosad Harav Cook), the old edition of the Chiddushe Haran and the new (I have a new edition but older than the Mosad Harav Cook edition). Some experts attribute the old edition of Chiddushe Haritba to the Ran, the old Ran's Chiddushim to an unknown Rishon.

Can someone clarify the topic for me?

- Who wrote the old Chidushe Haritba and the new;
- Who wrote the old Chidushe Haran and the new?
- Is there still a controversy?

Comment: You're asking specifically about the commentaries on שבת?

Comment: @msh210 yes, specifically.

Comment: I'm not in front of my sefarim to write up an authoritative answer, but I believe: 1. Old Ran is of unknown authorship, 2. New Ran = Old Ritva was authored by Ran, 3. New Ritva was authored by Ritva

Comment: @JoelK Are you sure the new Ran is the old Ritba, maybe a second Mahadura of the Ritba.

Comment: @kouty I'm not quite sure what you're asking. [This edition](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9610&st=&pgnum=1) of "Ritva" originally published as such in Salonika in 5566, was published by [Mosad Harav Kook](https://tablet.otzar.org/#/b/154742/p/5/t/1686059511938/fs/0/start/0/end/0/c/1686059546320) as "Ran"

Comment: @JoelK Indeed, I see in the Ritba Edition Mosad Harav Cook, the old Ran is an unknown Rishon and is called Shita Leharan. The old Ritba is from the Ran. The new Ran, is it the old Ritba or an other Mahdura of the Ran?

Comment: Look at the beginning of the MHK Ran to Shabbat that I linked in my above comment. They explain that what they printed now as Ran is what was previously printed (first in Salonica) as Ritva.

Comment: Compare the text of the two books I linked two in my earlier comment. You’ll see they are the same

Comment: @JoelK You're right. If you want to write an answer I'll approve it.

Comment: @kouty bli neder I will do. If anyone else is able to write something up first then they should feel feee to do so.